# React Native IOS build problem after upgrading

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

after upgrading react native version to 66.3 i have faced the following error .

*Uncategorized Group Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code*

[image]

```
Showing All Messages
  processRequest = (req, res, next) => {


Showing All Messages
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)

    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)

    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)

    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)

    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)

    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)

    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)

    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the Upgrade Helper?

Comment: sure!i followed all of them @jnpdx

Comment: Remove node_modules, yarn.lock and non cache.

Comment: already done but not working @MichaelBahl

Comment: Facing same problem. Any Solutions

Comment: in some cases the solution is your project is not looking in a right node path you should set it directly , in some other cases mismatches between some packages @Kartiikeya